# Gift aid uploaded declarations are only showing the first image for each entry

Tags: civicontribute, contacts, custom-fields, gift-aid-extension, upload

I have a gift aid issue - basically when you upload scanned declarations against a contact, they don't show each scanned image but only the first one repeadly (for each gift aid declaration entry). The rest of the text data remains the same for each entry.

The uploaded image I have added should make things clear - the red circles indicate a scanned declaration. The issue is that they are all the same image even though in the database I see different images referenced.

Also, when I click on 'Edit Gift Aid Declaration', clicking on the images for each entry shows the different uploaded images properly. So that is a workaround but not good as a HMRC officer won't be happy if someone doesn't know of that workaround!

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated. I had a stab at trying to see where in the codebase this bug is happening but its still a puzzle.

Cheers.

[image: First scanned image being duplicated for each different entry even when each entry has a different scanned image]

Comment: Which version of CiviCRM & GiftAid extension are you using?

Best

Comment: CiviCRM 4.7.22 and CiviCRM UK GiftAid is 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still has this problem, I can confirm that upgrading to at least 4.7.31 fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce the issue in GiftAid.

However, this appears to be a CiviCRM issue. I have also tested with a standard multi-submit custom fieldset containing a file upload field by submitting two different picture files. When I click on "View" submission, the same picture got shown in the modal.

[image: first submission]

[image: second submission]

I would recommend to open an issue in [CiviCRM core Jira](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa). If you are a developer yourself, you are more than welcome to submit a fix.

Best